# Conceptualized `operator auto` in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, auto, c++-concepts

Starting from C++20 we can precede `auto` keyword with the name of the concept to limit possible types. And in particular this combination is possible in class conversion `operator auto`, e.g.

```
template <typename T> concept x = true;

struct S
{
    operator x auto() { return 2; }
    operator auto() { return 1; }
};

int main() { return S{}.operator x auto(); }
```

But Clang is the only compiler that accepts the whole program, however `main()` returns `1` (and not `2` as I would expected), demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b16jYGa81

GCC accepts the struct definition, but refuses to compile `S{}.operator x auto()`.

And MSVC refuses to accept even `struct S` with the error:

```
error C2535: 'S::operator auto(void)': member function already defined or declared
```

Just wonder, which of the compilers is right here (if any)?

Comment: It is a bad practice to call operators explicitely. The intend of conversion operators in to simplify code and not to make it harder to read.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This conversion function:

```cpp
operator auto() { return 1; }
```

Means exactly the same as this converison function:

```cpp
operator int() { return 1; }
```

We're deducing the return type from `1`, this isn't a function template.

---

This conversion function:

```cpp
operator x auto() { return 2; }
```

Means roughly the same thing as:

```cpp
operator int() { static_assert(x<int>); return 2; }
```

We're deducing the return type from `2` and ensuring that that type (`int`) satisfies a particular concept (`x`).

---

Putting both together, we have two *functions* (neither is a function template), both of which are named `operator int()`, and that's just not allowed. This should be ill-formed even at the point of declaration since the name `operator int()` is bound to two conflicting declarations.

Note that the second one is still named `operator int()`, not `operator x auto()`.

Comment: Was there such a clarification? AFAIK, the language surrounding `operator auto` is too vague. Specifically, it doesn't say whether `operator auto` or `operator T` is the proper name (with `T` the deduced type).